# Cannot call a method from another method in the same class

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing an Angular 7 app and in this app I am using a "mention" plugin in an contenteditable div. When someone has selected a value from the dropdown a method is called and I can get the selected item but the problem is that I cannot call another method in the same class where I send this selected item to the server. I get the following error:

**The mentions library I use is this:**

```
https://github.com/dmacfarlane/angular-mentions
```

**This is my error**

```
PageContentComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: this.createBlock is not a function
```

**This is my class**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BaseComponent } from '../../../../shared/components/base.component';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-content',
  templateUrl: './page-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-content.component.scss']
})
export class PageContentComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, public api: HttpClient) { super(); }

  public path = 'pages';
  public model: any;

  ngOnInit() {}

  mentionSelect(selection): any {
    this.createBlock(selection);
    return selection.label;
  }

  createBlock(event) {
    this.isRunning = true;
    this.api.post(this.baseURL + 'blocks', {
        otype: event.type
      }).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.collection.splice(parseInt(event.index, 10) + 1, 0, data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
        this.isRunning = false;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Why can´t I run the method? It exists and is located in the same class as mentionSelect.

Comment: how does the page-content.component.html look like, at the place where it calls createBlock

Comment: I have created an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvqp4z) to show that the method is running. The error can be anything but running the method. I need details for `page-content.component.html` file for further investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the scope of `this` when `mentionSelect` is called. Change it to an arrow function so that `this` is properly captured. This is not necessary all the time but when registering events with external libraries it can happen.

```
mentionSelect = (selection): any => {
    this.createBlock(selection);
    return selection.label;
}

createBlock = (event) => {
    ....
```

Comment: this is can be confirmed by console.log(this) before the error line.

Comment: Works fine! Quick question, why use the = after the method name?

Comment: That assigns the field the arrow function @JonathanClark

Comment: Ah ok! Seems I dont need it on the actual createBlock method.

Comment: Correct @JonathanClark